# How to resolve the error "[FAILED] Compilation errors in the preload: group_0: [FAILED] assets by status 9.83 MiB [cached] 4 assets"?

Tags: node.js, electron, fiddle

I cloned the electron/fiddle from https://github.com/electron/fiddle, after solved all dependency problems, I got an error message when I try to run it use "npm run start":

```
[FAILED] Compilation errors in the preload: group_0:
[FAILED]   assets by status 9.83 MiB [cached] 4 assets
[FAILED]   assets by status 14.2 MiB [emitted]
[FAILED]     assets by path *.js 14 MiB
[FAILED]       asset ts.worker.js 10.3 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset css.worker.js 1.95 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset html.worker.js 1.29 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset editor.worker.js 447 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.js 374 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
[FAILED]     asset main_window/preload.js 251 KiB [emitted] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
[FAILED]     asset main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.json 35 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
[FAILED]   Entrypoint main_window 251 KiB (296 KiB) = main_window/preload.js 251 KiB main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.js 374 bytes 2 auxiliary assets
[FAILED]   cached modules 179 KiB [cached] 29 modules
[FAILED]   runtime modules 29.4 KiB 14 modules
[FAILED]   1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
[FAILED]   group_0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled with 1 warning in 767 ms
```

All contents on the terminal is:

```
$ cnpm start

> electron-fiddle@0.35.1 start
> rimraf ./.webpack && electron-forge start --

[STARTED] Checking your system
[STARTED] Checking git exists
[STARTED] Checking node version
[STARTED] Checking packageManager version
[TITLE] Found git@2.43.0.windows.1
[SUCCESS] Found git@2.43.0.windows.1
[TITLE] Found node@20.11.0
[SUCCESS] Found node@20.11.0
[TITLE] Found yarn@1.22.21
[SUCCESS] Found yarn@1.22.21
[SUCCESS] Checking your system
[STARTED] Locating application
[SUCCESS] Locating application
[STARTED] Loading configuration
[SUCCESS] Loading configuration
[STARTED] Preparing native dependencies
[TITLE] Preparing native dependencies
[SUCCESS] Preparing native dependencies
[STARTED] Running generateAssets hook
[STARTED] Running generateAssets hook from forgeConfig
Updating local releases.json with 2206 versions.
[SUCCESS] Running generateAssets hook from forgeConfig
[SUCCESS] Running generateAssets hook
[STARTED] [plugin-webpack] Compiling main process code
[SUCCESS] [plugin-webpack] Compiling main process code
[STARTED] [plugin-webpack] Launching dev servers for renderer process code
<i> [ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin] No errors found.
[FAILED] Compilation errors in the preload: group_0:
[FAILED]   assets by status 9.83 MiB [cached] 4 assets
[FAILED]   assets by status 14.2 MiB [emitted]
[FAILED]     assets by path *.js 14 MiB
[FAILED]       asset ts.worker.js 10.3 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset css.worker.js 1.95 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset html.worker.js 1.29 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset editor.worker.js 447 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.js 374 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
[FAILED]     asset main_window/preload.js 251 KiB [emitted] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
[FAILED]     asset main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.json 35 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
[FAILED]   Entrypoint main_window 251 KiB (296 KiB) = main_window/preload.js 251 KiB main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.js 374 bytes 2 auxiliary assets
[FAILED]   cached modules 179 KiB [cached] 29 modules
[FAILED]   runtime modules 29.4 KiB 14 modules
[FAILED]   1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
[FAILED]   group_0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled with 1 warning in 767 ms
[FAILED]
[FAILED] group_0:
[FAILED]   assets by status 30.2 MiB [emitted]
[FAILED]     assets by path *.js 14 MiB 4 assets
[FAILED]     assets by chunk 2.51 MiB (id hint: vendors) 4 assets
[FAILED]     assets by path main_window/ 13.5 MiB
[FAILED]       asset main_window/index.js 13.5 MiB [emitted] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
[FAILED]       asset main_window/index.html 716 bytes [emitted]
[FAILED]     assets by chunk 60.6 KiB (auxiliary name: main_window)
[FAILED]       asset fonts/codicon.ttf 59.6 KiB [emitted] [from: node_modules/.store/monaco-editor@0.21.3/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.ttf] (auxiliary name: main_window)
[FAILED]       asset native_modules/index.js 1.02 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main_window)
[FAILED]     + 4 assets
[FAILED]   assets by status 9.83 MiB [compared for emit]
[FAILED]     asset native_modules/typescript/lib/typescriptServices.js 8.35 MiB [compared for emit]
[FAILED]     asset native_modules/typescript/lib/lib.js 1.47 MiB [compared for emit]
[FAILED]     asset native_modules/typescript/lib/lib.index.js 2.78 KiB [compared for emit]
[FAILED]     asset native_modules/typescript/lib/typescriptServicesMetadata.js 138 bytes [compared for emit]
[FAILED]   Entrypoint main_window 13.7 MiB (13.1 MiB) = ./css/main_window.css 155 KiB main_window/index.js 13.5 MiB 4 auxiliary assets
[FAILED]   orphan modules 52.9 KiB [orphan] 23 modules
[FAILED]   runtime modules 34.4 KiB 20 modules
[FAILED]   modules by path ./node_modules/.store/ 12.4 MiB (javascript) 110 KiB (css/mini-extract)
[FAILED]     javascript modules 12.4 MiB 1635 modules
[FAILED]     css modules 110 KiB 70 modules
[FAILED]     ./node_modules/.store/@octokit+rest@16.43.2/node_modules/@octokit/res...(truncated) 3.76 KiB [built] [code generated]
[FAILED]   modules by path ./src/ 310 KiB
[FAILED]     modules by path ./src/renderer/ 300 KiB 69 modules
[FAILED]     modules by path ./src/*.ts 7.5 KiB 3 modules
[FAILED]     modules by path ./src/utils/*.ts 2.7 KiB
[FAILED]       ./src/utils/editor-utils.ts 1.52 KiB [built] [code generated]
[FAILED]       ./src/utils/gist.ts 1.18 KiB [built] [code generated]
[FAILED]     ./src/less/root.less 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
[FAILED]   ./package.json 4.69 KiB [built] [code generated]
[FAILED]   ./static/contributors.json 8.36 KiB [built] [code generated]
[FAILED]   1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
[FAILED]
[FAILED]   ERROR in ./src/less/root.less
[FAILED]   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.store/mini-css-extract-plugin@2.7.7/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
[FAILED]   ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.store/less-loader@11.1.4/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[FAILED]
[FAILED]
[FAILED]   @import (inline) "~@blueprintjs/select/lib/css/blueprint-select.css";
[FAILED]   @import (inline) "~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
[FAILED]   ^
[FAILED]   Less resolver error:
[FAILED]   '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css' wasn't found. Tried - D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css,npm://~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css,~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css
[FAILED]
[FAILED]   Webpack resolver error details:
[FAILED]   resolve '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css' in 'D:\codes\fiddle\src\less'
[FAILED]     Parsed request is a module
[FAILED]     using description file: D:\codes\fiddle\package.json (relative path: ./src/less)
[FAILED]       using description file: D:\codes\fiddle\package.json (relative path: ./src/less/~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css)
[FAILED]         no extension
[FAILED]           D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css doesn't exist
[FAILED]         .less
[FAILED]           D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css.less doesn't exist
[FAILED]         .css
[FAILED]           D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css.css doesn't exist
[FAILED]         as directory
[FAILED]           D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css doesn't exist
[FAILED]       resolve as module
[FAILED]         D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[FAILED]         D:\codes\fiddle\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[FAILED]         looking for modules in D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules
[FAILED]           D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\~@blueprintjs doesn't exist
[FAILED]         D:\codes\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[FAILED]         D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[FAILED]
[FAILED]   Webpack resolver error missing:
[FAILED]   undefined
[FAILED]
[FAILED]
[FAILED]         Error in D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\blueprint.less (line 3, column 0)
[FAILED]       at processResult (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:764:19)
[FAILED]       at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:866:5
[FAILED]       at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\loader-runner@4.3.0\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:400:11
[FAILED]       at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\loader-runner@4.3.0\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
[FAILED]       at context.callback (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\loader-runner@4.3.0\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
[FAILED]       at Object.lessLoader (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\less-loader@11.1.4\node_modules\less-loader\dist\index.js:61:5)
[FAILED]    @ ./src/renderer/app.tsx 17:0-28
[FAILED]    @ ./src/renderer/main.tsx 5:14-30
[FAILED]
[FAILED]   1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
[FAILED]   group_0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning in 23475 ms

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Compilation errors in the preload: group_0:
  assets by status 9.83 MiB [cached] 4 assets
  assets by status 14.2 MiB [emitted]
    assets by path *.js 14 MiB
      asset ts.worker.js 10.3 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
      asset css.worker.js 1.95 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
      asset html.worker.js 1.29 MiB [emitted] 1 related asset
      asset editor.worker.js 447 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
      asset main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.js 374 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
    asset main_window/preload.js 251 KiB [emitted] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
    asset main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.json 35 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
  Entrypoint main_window 251 KiB (296 KiB) = main_window/preload.js 251 KiB main_window.9241706583a34d34e821.hot-update.js 374 bytes 2 auxiliary assets
  cached modules 179 KiB [cached] 29 modules
  runtime modules 29.4 KiB 14 modules
  1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
  group_0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled with 1 warning in 767 ms

group_0:
  assets by status 30.2 MiB [emitted]
    assets by path *.js 14 MiB 4 assets
    assets by chunk 2.51 MiB (id hint: vendors) 4 assets
    assets by path main_window/ 13.5 MiB
      asset main_window/index.js 13.5 MiB [emitted] (name: main_window) 1 related asset
      asset main_window/index.html 716 bytes [emitted]
    assets by chunk 60.6 KiB (auxiliary name: main_window)
      asset fonts/codicon.ttf 59.6 KiB [emitted] [from: node_modules/.store/monaco-editor@0.21.3/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.ttf] (auxiliary name: main_window)
      asset native_modules/index.js 1.02 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main_window)
    + 4 assets
  assets by status 9.83 MiB [compared for emit]
    asset native_modules/typescript/lib/typescriptServices.js 8.35 MiB [compared for emit]
    asset native_modules/typescript/lib/lib.js 1.47 MiB [compared for emit]
    asset native_modules/typescript/lib/lib.index.js 2.78 KiB [compared for emit]
    asset native_modules/typescript/lib/typescriptServicesMetadata.js 138 bytes [compared for emit]
  Entrypoint main_window 13.7 MiB (13.1 MiB) = ./css/main_window.css 155 KiB main_window/index.js 13.5 MiB 4 auxiliary assets
  orphan modules 52.9 KiB [orphan] 23 modules
  runtime modules 34.4 KiB 20 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/.store/ 12.4 MiB (javascript) 110 KiB (css/mini-extract)
    javascript modules 12.4 MiB 1635 modules
    css modules 110 KiB 70 modules
    ./node_modules/.store/@octokit+rest@16.43.2/node_modules/@octokit/res...(truncated) 3.76 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/ 310 KiB
    modules by path ./src/renderer/ 300 KiB 69 modules
    modules by path ./src/*.ts 7.5 KiB 3 modules
    modules by path ./src/utils/*.ts 2.7 KiB
      ./src/utils/editor-utils.ts 1.52 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./src/utils/gist.ts 1.18 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/less/root.less 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  ./package.json 4.69 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./static/contributors.json 8.36 KiB [built] [code generated]
  1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

  ERROR in ./src/less/root.less
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.store/mini-css-extract-plugin@2.7.7/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
  ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.store/less-loader@11.1.4/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


  @import (inline) "~@blueprintjs/select/lib/css/blueprint-select.css";
  @import (inline) "~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
  ^
  Less resolver error:
  '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css' wasn't found. Tried - D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css,npm://~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css,~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css

  Webpack resolver error details:
  resolve '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css' in 'D:\codes\fiddle\src\less'
    Parsed request is a module
    using description file: D:\codes\fiddle\package.json (relative path: ./src/less)
      using description file: D:\codes\fiddle\package.json (relative path: ./src/less/~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css)
        no extension
          D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css doesn't exist
        .less
          D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css.less doesn't exist
        .css
          D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css.css doesn't exist
        as directory
          D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\~@blueprintjs\icons\lib\css\blueprint-icons.css doesn't exist
      resolve as module
        D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
        D:\codes\fiddle\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
        looking for modules in D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules
          D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\~@blueprintjs doesn't exist
        D:\codes\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
        D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

  Webpack resolver error missing:
  undefined


        Error in D:\codes\fiddle\src\less\blueprint.less (line 3, column 0)
      at processResult (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:764:19)
      at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:866:5
      at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\loader-runner@4.3.0\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:400:11
      at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\loader-runner@4.3.0\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
      at context.callback (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\loader-runner@4.3.0\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
      at Object.lessLoader (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\less-loader@11.1.4\node_modules\less-loader\dist\index.js:61:5)
   @ ./src/renderer/app.tsx 17:0-28
   @ ./src/renderer/main.tsx 5:14-30

  1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
  group_0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning in 23475 ms
at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\@electron-forge+plugin-webpack@7.2.0\node_modules\@electron-forge\plugin-webpack\src\WebpackPlugin.ts:395:27
    at Hook.eval (eval at create (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\tapable@2.2.1\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\tapable@2.2.1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:97:22
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\tapable@2.2.1\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:29:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\tapable@2.2.1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Watching._done (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:299:28)
    at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:213:21
    at Compiler.emitRecords (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:919:5)
    at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:191:22
    at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:885:14
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\tapable@2.2.1\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\tapable@2.2.1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\webpack@5.89.0\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:882:27
    at D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\neo-async@2.6.2\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (D:\codes\fiddle\node_modules\.store\neo-async@2.6.2\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
```

And the content of package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "electron-fiddle",
  "productName": "Electron Fiddle",
  "version": "0.35.1",
  "description": "The easiest way to get started with Electron",
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/fiddle",
  "homepage": "https://electronjs.org/fiddle",
  "main": "./.webpack/main",
  "scripts": {
    "contributors": "ts-node ./tools/contributors.ts",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"./src/less/*.less\"",
    "lint:ts": "eslint \"./**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "lint:js": "eslint \"./**/*.js\"",
    "lint:markdown": "electron-markdownlint \"*.md\"",
    "lint:templates": "standard \"static/**/*.js\"",
    "lint:links": "electron-lint-markdown-links --root . --fetch-external-links \"*.md\"",
    "lint:fix": "npm-run-all \"lint:!(fix) -- --fix\"",
    "lint": "npm-run-all \"lint:!(fix)\"",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "start": "rimraf ./.webpack && electron-forge start --",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci --coverage --runInBand --reporters=jest-junit",
    "test:report": "jest --json --bail=false --outputFile=report.json | true",
    "tsc": "tsc --noEmit -p .",
    "electron-releases": "node --unhandled-rejections=strict -r ts-node/register ./tools/fetch-releases.ts",
    "postinstall": "husky install && npm run electron-releases"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "Fiddle",
    "Tutorial"
  ],
  "author": "Felix Rieseberg <felix@felixrieseberg.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": "./forge.config.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.36.0",
    "@blueprintjs/popover2": "^0.12.2",
    "@blueprintjs/select": "^3.15.0",
    "@electron/fiddle-core": "^1.3.2",
    "@octokit/rest": "^16.43.1",
    "@sentry/electron": "^4.10.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.12.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "commander": "^7.1.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "electron-default-menu": "^1.0.2",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-zip": "^2.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
    "getos": "^3.2.1",
    "mobx": "^6.5.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.3.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.21.3",
    "namor": "^2.0.2",
    "node-watch": "^0.7.3",
    "p-debounce": "^2.0.0",
    "package-json": "^7.0.0",
    "parse-env-string": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-mosaic-component": "^4.1.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.7",
    "semver": "^7.3.4",
    "shell-env": "^3.0.1",
    "tmp": "0.2.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@algolia/client-search": "^4.22.1",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/publisher-github": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/shared-types": "7.2.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.6.1",
    "@electron/lint-roller": "^1.0.1",
    "@octokit/core": "^3.5.1",
    "@reforged/maker-appimage": "^3.3.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.11",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.7",
    "@types/getos": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/log-symbols": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "@types/recursive-readdir": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/semver": "^7.3.4",
    "@types/tmp": "0.2.0",
    "@types/valid-url": "^1.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^1.7.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "electron": "25.8.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.5",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "fetch-mock-jest": "^1.5.1",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
    "jest-mock": "^29.7.0",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "log-symbols": "^4.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.25",
    "postcss-less": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "recursive-readdir": "^2.2.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "standard": "^17.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^15.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.69.1"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./**/*.js": [
      "npm run lint:js -- --fix"
    ],
    "./**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run lint:ts -- --fix"
    ],
    "./static/**/*.js": [
      "npm run lint:templates -- --fix"
    ],
    "./src/less/*.less": [
      "npm run lint:style -- --fix"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@electron-forge/maker-base": "7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/shared-types": "7.2.0"
  }
}
```

I searched for relevant keywords on the Internet and couldn't find a solution, and reinstalling the css-loader version to 5.0.0 has no effect.